# Listen to ViewHolders in RecyclerView being recycled

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Is it possible to register a listener with a `RecyclerView` so that I can be notified whenever a a view within a `ViewHolder` is *recycled* i.e. `onBindViewHolder(~)` called?

I do not have the ability to modify the RecyclerView or the attached Adapter (if there is one).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a lambda function on Adapter's constructor and listen onViewRecycled method of ListAdapter or RecyclerView.Adapter

```
class MyAdapter(val onViewRecycled:(Int) -> Unit) :
        ListAdapter<Any, CustomViewHolder>(AnyDiffCallback()) {



    override fun onViewRecycled(holder: CustomViewHolder) {
        super.onViewRecycled(holder)
        onViewRecycled(holder.absoluteAdapterPosition)
        
    }
}
```

If you cannot access adapter then you can use `addOnChildAttachStateChangeListener` with `RecyclerView`

```
recyclerView.addOnChildAttachStateChangeListener(object:
            RecyclerView.OnChildAttachStateChangeListener {
            override fun onChildViewDetachedFromWindow(view: View) {

            }

            override fun onChildViewAttachedToWindow(view: View) {

            }

        })
```